# Rename \maketitle to include affiliation

Tags: macros, titles, renewcommand

I have never used advanced tex macros before, so I am pretty new here. Please don't judge me too harshly!

I need to modify the behaviour of the `\maketitle` command. I'd like to be able to add a custom function called `\affiliation` inside it, so when `\maketitle` is executed, the `\affiliation` command is executed as well. Below is my naive approach:

```
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{\parskip=-15pt
 $^1$\footnotesize{\textit{#1}}\parskip=20pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
  \lineskip .5em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    \@author
  \end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
\@affiliation
\vskip 1em
%{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
% ------------------------
 \title{Title}
 \author{My name}
 \affiliation{whatever}
%---------------------------

 \begin{document}
   \maketitle
 \end{document}
```

However that doesn't seem to work. I am getting a compilation error in "Overleaf" `Latex Error: Missing \begin{document}`. Any idea how to solve it?
Your help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: \title stores the title in \@title,  while \affiliation prints the affiliation.  Use `\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{\edef\@afilliation{...}}`  OTOH, it is better to put the formatting into \maketitle than \edef.

Comment: @ John Kormylo I am sorry but that unfortunately doesn't work! I am getting : `Runaway argument?
{\def \@affiliation{\textit {##1}} \par \makeatletter \def \@maketitl\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex
            
I suspect you have forgotten a }, causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's really impossible to answer this question without knowing what document class you're using.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ahhh, I am so sorry! I am using the "article" document class

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code you can use the following. OTOH, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with `\parskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{\edef\@affiliation{#1}}

\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
  \lineskip .5em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
    \@author
  \end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
%%%%%%%%
\parskip=-15pt
 $^1$\footnotesize{\textit{\@affiliation}}\parskip=20pt
%%%%%%%%
\vskip 1em
%{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
% ------------------------
 \title{Title}
 \author{My name}
 \affiliation{whatever}
%---------------------------

 \begin{document}
   \maketitle
 \end{document}
```